# Web API 2: OData 4: Possible bug with GUIDs?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I've updated my solution to use `OData v4` for `Web API 2` - I was previously using`OData v3`. For some reason, some of the routes are giving a 404 error where they were working perfectly fine before. These routes are anything with the entity key/ID.. example:

```
[EnableQuery]
    public virtual SingleResult<TEntity> Get([FromODataUri] TKey key)
    {
```

and

```
public virtual IHttpActionResult Delete([FromODataUri] TKey key)
        {
```

As I said, they were working perfectly fine before, but now I am getting a 404 for these. Other routes, such as below, are fine:

```
[EnableQuery]
        public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Get()
        {
```

and

```
public virtual IHttpActionResult Post(TEntity entity)
        {
```

Note that my entities are sending `GUID`s for the ID. Is there maybe a bug with `GUID`s in `OData 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, yes... confirmed as something wrong.. I would say it's a bug.. but maybe MS has some strange reason for it; Anyway, here's a link to the issue on CodePlex:

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/885

Basically, in `OData v3`, you would query like this: `/odata/Something(guid'some-guid-here')`, but in `OData 4`, it's changed to: `/odata/Something(some-guid-here)`